# Event machine error in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

While updating my Rails application's bundle it shows me the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/mspd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150105-24447-rayukd.rb extconf.rb 
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling em.cpp
em.cpp: In member function ‘void EventMachine_t::_RunEpollOnce()’:
em.cpp:574:37: error: ‘rb_thread_select’ was not declared in this scope
   EmSelect (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                                     ^
em.cpp: In member function ‘int SelectData_t::_Select()’:
em.cpp:827:67: error: ‘rb_thread_select’ was not declared in this scope
  return EmSelect (maxsocket+1, &fdreads, &fdwrites, &fderrors, &tv);
                                                                   ^
em.cpp: In member function ‘void EventMachine_t::_RunSelectOnce()’:
em.cpp:946:40: error: ‘rb_thread_select’ was not declared in this scope
      EmSelect (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                                        ^
make: *** [em.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/mspd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/mspd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I tried `gem install eventmachine` it still shows the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: It seems you're using ruby-2.2.0, which is shiny and new. Did you check with eventmachine's issue tracker if there are any reports of it not working (yet) with ruby-2.2.0?

Answer (score 2):

I am no EventMachine maintainer, but EventMachine probably will never support Ruby 2.2.0, as they only accept security patches, but they don't actively accept features PRs.

They also mention this in the public [README](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine#what-platforms-are-supported-by-eventmachine):

> What platforms are supported by EventMachine?
>
> EventMachine supports Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, REE, JRuby and works well on
>   Windows as well as many operating systems from the Unix family (Linux,
>   Mac OS X, BSD flavors).

**Solution: Fall back to Ruby 1.9.2 or use an alternative to [EventMachine](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Concurrent_Processing).**

Answer (score 0):

Try with

gem update eventmachine